# Merge tags conditioning and condition-number?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I'd like to suggest merging these two tags for the following reasons.

- Both tags are under-utilized; many questions cover the topic of matrix conditioning, either in statement or in answers, but are not tagged as such.  This may occur in part due to tag ambiguity.
- There are only 4 questions tagged with [conditioning](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditioning) compared to 16 with [condition-number](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/condition-number), but the topics covered are essentially identical.
- The notions of matrix conditioning and condition number are inextricably linked; the former refers to the magnitude of the latter.

Is there any reason we should keep these tags separate or hesitate in enacting a global merge?

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, I think one should keep both tags. Mainly because they cannot be merged in a straight-forward manner.

1. The tag [condition-number](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/condition-number) is commonly understood as referring to the special case of [conditioning](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditioning) of linear systems. Thus, it seems necessary to keep the tag 'conditioning' as it contains both.
2. As indicated by the number of questions, the 'condition-number' is of particular interest and, thus, should be kept as a tag.

**EDIT:**
However, in practice, because of rare appearance and because it can be replaced by a combination of 'condition-number' and 'nonlinear-equations' in case it indeed refers to nonlinear problems, I think it is safe to **abandon** the tag [conditioning](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditioning).

Comment: In what sense is conditioning used not in reference to linear systems? At least 3 of the 4 posts tagged with [tag:conditioning] refer to the conditioning of linear systems, and thus implicitly to condition number.

Comment: Generally, conditioning is about error propagation of a functional.  If $f$ measures the deviation in the solution $x$ of $Ax=b$ for a disturbance in $b$, one ends up with a parameter that is referred to as condition number.

Comment: But I see your point. Obviously, 'conditioning' is not needed here. And it can be safely replaced by the combination 'condition-number' and 'nonlinear-equations', since the condition number is also defined for (the linearization of) nonlinear operations. Let me edit my answer accordingly.